# Bash - check if sub directory contains folder

Tags: bash

**What I am trying to do:**

I want every directory in the home folder to contain a shared folder where I will put some shared files for everyone to read. I also stored the shared folder in home. The directory structure looks like this:

```
home
---user1
------shared
------someFolder
---user2
------someFolder
---shared
```

I want to make sure I am not inserting a link to the shared folder inside itself. I also want to check if the folders have a link to the shared folder. If it already has a link then do nothing. If it does not have a link then create one.

Here is my code:

```
for d in */ ; do
    if [ "$d" != "shared/" ]
    then
        shared_exists=false
        for e in "$d"*/; do
            #echo "$e"
            if [ "$e" = $d"shared/" ]
            then
                shared_exists=true
            fi
        done
        if [ "$shared_exists" = true ]
        then
            echo "shared exists in $d"
        else
            echo "Shared does not exist in $d"
            sudo ln -s /home/shared/ /home/"$d"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Is this the correct way or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor that code to this much shorter code:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
cd /home

for d in !(shared)/; do
    [[ ! -e "$d"shared ]] && ln -s "$PWD/shared" "$d"shared
done
```

Comment: Consider adding some check for `cd` :)

Comment: ha ha :) ya sure: `cd /home || exit 1`